# Generating PowerPoint slides with R Markdown and a built-in Microsoft theme

Tags: r, themes, powerpoint, r-markdown

I'm using R Markdown to generate PowerPoint slides, Is there a way I could ask R Markdown to use the Microsoft built-in themes for the slides?

Comment: You could customize the format elements of slides with `*.css` files. See here https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532307-Customizing-Fonts-and-Appearance

Comment: The reason I moved away from MS ppt  is that its build-in themes are ugly...

Comment: Another option of doing rmarkdown presentation is `xaringan`, there's a wiki for the theme customization : https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/wiki